# CSS Transition.. Make the text move up from the bottom

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design, css-transitions

```
<style type="text/css">
   .button2 {
       font-family: "Georgia Pro", Georgia;
       background: #000;
       color: #fff;
       text-decoration: none;
       padding: 5px 15px;
       border: 3px solid #000;
       font-size: 14px;
   }

   .button2:hover {
       border: 3px solid #000;
       background: #fff;
       color:#000;
   }
</style>

<a href="#link" class="button2" title="ADD TO SHOPPING BAG"><span>ADD TO SHOPPING BAG</span></a>
```

This is my code. I want to make it so that when the user moves over the link, the hover box moves from the bottom or top and comes in? I am very new to CSS3 transitions and don't understand the whole `s` and `width` thing or `height`? The only thing is I want it more or less maybe fluid and better to handle responsive design.. think `em` and `auto` height??

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ysr7W/2/

Sample hover:

[image]

Comment: you really want to use css3? Not every browser supports it. If I were you, I would use jquery

Comment: Most of the site does not use jQuery - I have thought of the approach but with CSS3 it feels more fluid; responsive etc.. no JavaScript for this one..

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid check this link: http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_animations.asp

Comment: @Sonhja I have seen the link but I don't know how to implement it vertically I have seen many links and tutorials

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid I almost get it, but this is more or less the way: http://jsfiddle.net/Ysr7W/5/   Also check this link: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#properties-from-css-

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although i think CSS isn't the right language for this effect, i did try to create something for you. The code isn't perfect, but it does what you requested: http://jsfiddle.net/Ysr7W/9/

The HTML structure i used:

```
<a href="#" class="button">
    <span class="white">ADD TO SHOPPING BAG</span>
    <span class="black">ADD TO SHOPPING BAG</span>
</a>​
```

Comment: I was going to do this, have two. But it is duplication and just not the logical way. I thought of this. Repped. I think I will try to improve off your code and then re post the answer if possible.

Comment: The only other thing.. thought although I like this solution. It is not fluid; does not use `em` or `auto` for width and height. I want this for mobile and web use you - responsive to size and device screen width.. so .. I don't know